# Corrupt RAR recovery

Tags: winrar, file-corruption

I have a damaged, password protected RAR archive. I've recovered it after the disk has been accidentally formatted.

It has correct size as it had before format, I can open it using WinRAR and enter the password.
Then I'm greeted with the

!   C:\path\to\file: Checksum error in the encrypted file C:\path\to\file\file.rar. Corrupt file or wrong password.

I can, however, see and extract first 9 files of the archive. It also shows 10th file, but this one seems to be a problem cause it's extraction fails with the same error and there are no files listed after it. Archive contains around 100 files.

This is what I've tried without success:

1. Different RAR extraction software
2. Built in repair tools in WinRAR
3. Several small RAR repair tools commonly found on the first
   pages of google search for "RAR repair" and similar

None of them gave nothing more besides those 9 files.

Now, content of this archive is very important to me, and I'm willing to go pretty far to get them back. So basically, what I'm asking for is some of the following:

1. Software recommendation - I don't care if free or not, win/linux is fine. Thus far only Recovery Toolbox for RAR looked promising as it actually went through the blocks and took few hours to complete. Got 10 files only though, with the last one corrupt.
2. Short explanation/link on RAR structure and ideas how to do it 'manually'. I can write code, but I'm unsure weather this is possible at all, so I don't do it in vain. My best guess is that some blocks on the disk where archive was got overwritten, and that destroyed internal structure, EOFs or file headers or something along these lines. So I was thinking if I could decrypt the file and then scan for headers and try to fix the problem. After all, something is obviously there and I'm able to get part of the data back as-is.
3. Any other ideas (maybe some way to skip extracting the corrupt
   files...)

My last option is to give the archive to some specialized data restoration company, but only if there is absolutely no other way.

Comment: When you say "correct size as it had before format" is that to the byte; or is it the rounded number to the KB/MB that Windows displays? I.e. Windows will show 79 byte files as 1kb... and I'll guess it'll show 90 byte files as, also, being 1kb... using Explorer to view the files isn't useful when dealing with broken files. I have a feeling your file content has been overwritten - it'll be almost impossible to recover without a backup in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract corrupted RAR files](http://superuser.com/questions/305355/how-to-extract-corrupted-rar-files)